# how to merge codes in c# with passing parameters?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to have this line

```
var newlist = listOrder.OrderBy(i => i.Date).ToList().GetRange(jtStartIndex, jtPageSize)
```

and this line of code together?

```
_repository.ReportRepository.GetTracks(jtStartIndex, jtPageSize, jtSorting);
```

I tried by adding an Operator but it doesn't work. i.e. like this:

```
var newlist = listOrder.OrderBy(i => i.Date).ToList().GetRange(jtStartIndex, jtPageSize) + _repository.ReportRepository.GetTracks(jtStartIndex, jtPageSize, jtSorting);
```

Full Controller Code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult StudentList(string StartDate = "", string EndDate = "", int jtStartIndex = 0, int jtPageSize = 0, string jtSorting = null)
        {

            try
        {

            if (Request.IsAuthenticated == true)
            {
                string Path = @"C:\\5Newwithdate-1k.xls";
                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= '" + Path + "';Extended Properties=" + (char)34 + "Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;" + (char)34 + "");
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", con);
                con.Close();
                System.Data.DataTable data = new System.Data.DataTable();
                da.Fill(data);

                List<TopPlayed> daa = new List<TopPlayed>();
                foreach (DataRow p in data.Rows)
                {
                    TopPlayed top = new TopPlayed()
                    {
                        TrackID = Convert.ToInt32(p.Field<double>("TrackID")),
                        Date = p.Field<DateTime>("DateTimes"),
                        TrackName = p.Field<string>("TrackName"),
                        ArtistName = p.Field<string>("ArtistName"),
                        Times = Convert.ToInt32(p.Field<double>("Times"))
                    };

                    daa.Add(top);
                }

                // var newlist = listOrder.OrderBy(i => i.Date).ToList().GetRange(jtStartIndex, jtPageSize) _repository.ReportRepository.GetTracks(jtStartIndex, jtPageSize, jtSorting);

                var newlist = _repository.ReportRepository.GetTracks(jtStartIndex, jtPageSize, jtSorting).OrderBy(i => i.Date).ToList().GetRange(jtStartIndex, jtPageSize);

                return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = newlist, TotalRecordCount = daa.Count });
```

Comment: Possibly union if the datatypes are compatible: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: is the repository returning listOrder or are they two different things?

Comment: @MatthewMartin - thanks for that and I'll give it a go.. is it possible for you to post an example if you don't mind? I'm not very familiar with merging Unions. I'll try on my side too... thanks :=)

Comment: @RyanSchlueter - thanks for that and yes it is returning listOrder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be under thinking what your trying to do if so let me know.

```
var newlist = _repository.ReportRepository.GetTracks(jtStartIndex, jtPageSize, jtSorting).OrderBy(i => i.Date).ToList().GetRange(jtStartIndex, jtPageSize);
```

Comment: what u did there is bang on! your fix compiled! - thanks :) After compiling I got the following error "Error communicating to the Server" on the View. I have updated my code for your inspection, if you think anything is missing? and thanks again :)